# Dirshu Daf Hayomi B'Halacha

Tags: halacha, internet, adult-learning

Two questions :

1) How do I get *Dirshu halacha shiurim* on *Kol Halashon* AND 
2) Is there a way that I could see the current schedule online ?

Answer (score 1):

[calling information for Dirshu on Kol Halashon](http://www.teaneckshuls.org/daf/misc/Daf_Hayomi_BHalacha_5775.pdf)

Phone:
   888-5-DIRSHU

Address:
212 Second St., Suite 404B 
Lakewood, NJ, 08701

Fax:
732-987-3949

E-mail:
    info@kolleldirshu.org

Comment: there is no up-to-date schedule though

Answer (score 0):

Dirshu Mishnah Brurah shiurim are available on line at OU Torah / Halacha / Mishnah Brurah.

Comment: Hi Aharon, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your answer!  Is this the correct link?  https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha-series/mishnah-brurah-yomi/#?

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, which specifically asked for a Kol HaLashon link.